# Libav multi-threaded decoding

Tags: c++, c, libav, libavcodec

According to the documentation [here](https://wiki.libav.org/Internals/CodecHowTo#Multi_threading_support), Libav provides the "infrastructure" for multithreaded decoding. But the docs are vague and confusing regarding how multithreaded decoding is implemented. Is it internally supported and just requires setting a flag in the struct, or does the user have to provide his own implementation with the provided functions? I searched a lot but could not find even one example of multithreaded video decoding with libav.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The link you have referred to looks like a description towards codec developers rather than to end-user of FFmpeg libraries using existing codecs.

Multi-threaded support is indeed implemented by framework itself - it requires FFmpeg to be built with thread support (like `--enable-pthreads` or `--enable-w32threads` configure options), varies across specific codecs (e.g. one codec may support multiple threads while others don't) and implement different approaches (decoding multiple frames in parallel or multiple slices within a single frame).

End-user application may configure the [number of threads](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/structAVCodecContext.html) to utilize (via `AVCodecContext::thread_count` property set before `avcodec_open2()`) and threaded mode (`AVCodecContext::thread_type` set to `FF_THREAD_FRAME` or `FF_THREAD_SLICE`). Thread pool will be managed by FFmpeg itself, although [some answers say](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44658374/ffmpeg-parallel-encoding-with-custom-thread-pool) that it is also possible using application-provided pool.

Some documents refer that `AVCodecContext::thread_count` default value set to `0` allows FFmpeg to automatically decide how many threads to use (which will be done based on a number of logical CPUs in system), but I've never tried this (always set this parameter manually). So probably it already does multi-threaded decoding on your system - check CPU load in task manager.

What FFmpeg doesn't do is managing multiple threads for reading packets from a file, decoding different streams in different threads and other similar things which a video player normally does - this is normally implemented by application itself. Although I recall some features have been integrated to FFmpeg simplifying implementation of these routines (like a packets queue).